# need help about how to add Menu page

Tags: iphone

i'm download DrillDownApp example project from iPhoneSDKArticles

i have a problem when i'm try to add menu page
before load MainWindow.

i can't load [window addSubview:[navigationController view]]; on other class except on DrillDownAppAppDelegate.m

could you explane me or give me some tutorial how to add menu page on DrillDownApp please

i'm new to iphone development, need some advise please , thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not entirely sure on what you want to achieve, but I think you want to add a view to something that is not the appDelegate that instantiates the navigationController.

To add view to the navigationController you use:

```
    MYViewController *viewController = [[MYViewCOntroller alloc]
                                            initWithNibName:@"MYViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

If you just want to add a view to another view you should use:

```
    MYViewController *viewController = [[MYViewCOntroller alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"MYViewController" 
                                    bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView:viewController.view]
```

Was this what you needed?
:)